# is it safe to use reference in structures to other structures

Tags: c++

I have 2 structures in one `DataStorage` structure. What I want in the end is to have possiblity to use first structure independently and also to be able to save `DataStorage` and to be sure that first two are going to be saved. This may not be relevant, because the question is - is this code safe?

Please take a look at code, it ilustrates all much better.
I believe my approach is OK, but my fear has ever since been to use pointers and references because of memory leaks and other unexpected behaviours.

```
#include < iostream > 
#include < string >
  //---------------------------
  //two structures to hold some data
  //and a structure to hold 2 structures
  struct settings_t {
    uint8_t myBaseID = 68;
    uint8_t reserved1;
  } settingsD;

struct values_t {
  unsigned long longValue0;
};

//struct in question, will also later be passed to template class like
//some_template_type <DataStorage>save; 
struct DataStorage {
  settings_t & settings = settingsD;
  values_t valueStore;
};
//--------------------------
//function that generates new structure
settings_t generateNew() {
    settings_t ret;
    ret.myBaseID = 66;
    return ret;
  }
  //new test instance of datastorage
void test1() {
  DataStorage ds1;
  std::cout << "Hello, " << ds1.settings.myBaseID << "!\n";
}

int main() {
  DataStorage ds;
  ds.settings.myBaseID = 65;

  std::cout << "Hello, " << ds.settings.myBaseID << "!\n";
  std::cout << "Hello, " << settingsD.myBaseID << "!\n";
  test1();

  ds.settings = generateNew();

  std::cout << "Hello, " << ds.settings.myBaseID << "!\n";
  std::cout << "Hello, " << settingsD.myBaseID << "!\n";
  test1();
}
```

And the result is (as desired):

```
Hello, A!
Hello, A!
Hello, A!
Hello, B!
Hello, B!
Hello, B!
```

Comment: This might be better to post a code review instead of here.  FWIW I do not see anything unsafe.

Comment: I'd advise against it as you're always a hair's breadth away from a dangling reference. Also, ending a type with `_t` is to be discouraged. POSIX explicitly forbids it. (That said, the cool cats like to rebel against this.)

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not familiar with "code review", but I will google that out.

Comment: @nekitip [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Bathsheba, you mean _t as is in `settings_t` or uint8_t?

Comment: @nekitip Don't listen to him. He tries to enforce you to use coding style which he likes

Comment: @V.Kravchenko. Love it. Don't blame me, blame POSIX. Yes, I do mean things like `settings_t`. Use `_type` for your types instead. Pretty please, with sugar on top.

Comment: What's the point? All instances of `DataStorage` hold a reference to the same global variable. Any reason you can't just use that global variable directly?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik He probably thinks that by `ds.settings = generateNew();` he changes the reference

Comment: @V.Kravchenko I don't think so. After that assignment, the OP prints both `ds.settings.myBaseID` and `settingsD.myBaseID`, gets the same value, and pronounces that to be desired behavior. So they seem to be cognizant of the fact that `ds.settings.myBaseID` and `settingsD.myBaseID` are perfect synonyms.

Comment: In this example it is fine because the reference is bound to an object that lasts as long as the program. In general it is fine **only** when the referenced object *outlives* the object that is referring to it. It is a strong, life-time coupling. That needs to be inherent in the design.

Comment: @Galik, so `ds1` in `test1()` is safely disposed, and at any time I can create new `settings_t` like in `generateNew`?

Comment: In **this** example it doesn't mater how many `settings_t` objects you create because **all** `DataStorage` objects will *always* only ever refer to the global variable `settingsD`. All your `generateNew()` does is overwrite the values in the global variable `settingsD`.

Comment: thank you all, esspecially @Galik!